# How to delete entire system using Terminal

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

How can I delete my entire system using terminal? I know that the beginning is `rm`, but then what?

Comment: I have the root. :)

Comment: Upvoting because it's sheer insanity captured in a 9 word question. :)

Comment: Upvote for sheer amusement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As root, you could do:

```
rm -rf --no-preserve-root /
```

Normally, we try to avoid these things. :)

Comment: Thanks. I am currently doing it on my own computer, I just want to see _definitivly_ how far it will go.

Comment: @Odinulf: All the way. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda` may be easier, though ;)

Comment: @Odinulf - Indeed, use your power wisely. This will wipe everything...

Comment: Hmm, I did `rm -rf/` and the terminal came out with this: `rm: illegal option -- /`

Comment: and `/dev/sda` is not supported.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Odinulf, don't forget the space between the forward slash: `rm -rf /`

Comment: I suggest trying this at least once in a virtual environment if you've done it. It's amazing to see what happens when you do something wrong. Like `rm -rf / usr/` would've messed things up a long time ago.

Answer (score 8):

Most modern Linux distributions actually disable the ability of removing root by default So to get through this you would use the `--no-preserve-root`flag.

The complete code to remove the root directory (/) is

> `rm -rf --no-preserve-root /`

you would need to run this as root though.

Another way of doing this is using dd the command for this is

> `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd[x]`

where `[x]` is the drive you want to erase. This rewrites each bit of your drive to 0 which permanently erases everything.

Comment: Plus, the filesystem errors encountered by using `dd` are quite fun ;) I did the second on my home box, meaning to zero out a flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by deleting, you might get better results by

```
# for d in /dev/[sh]d? ; do dd if=/dev/zero of=${d} ; done ;
```